# when I get vite build I need to change the file path

Tags: vite

When I build with vite, I need to put . at the beginning of the file path of the javascript and css file in the index.html file in the dist.

can I set this via config please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vite by default sets the default path to '/', you need to override it to use your project default path for the production build.

Go to your vite.config.ts (or vite.config.js if you have a JS project) and add the base option like below:

```
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  base: '',
})
```